# "Filled" custom stainless steel washer or alternatives for solderless contact

Tags: contact

*My apologies if this isn't the right stack exchange to ask in, I can't figure out which one to post in.*

I am currently trying to make a solder-less electrical contact by squeezing a nickel strip between 2 washers:

[image: screw washers and strip]

As you can see in the picture, there is a smaller washer below the big one (just "above" the screw head). This is because the bigger washer's hole is too big, so the screw head just goes through.

I need to remove the smaller washer as it blocks the big washer from properly contacting the surface that will be pressed in from below (the screw head is small enough that it doesn't interfere, but the small washer does.)

I am looking to remove both bottom washers, and replacing them with a filled disk of the same diameter, then drilling the hole myself. I haven't been able to find raw metal disks of a given diameter anywhere.

*An "ideal" washer for this would be 3mm inner diameter (because the screw is M3) and 17-18 outer diameter (due to the receptacle blocking the washer from moving sideways). Or simply a 17-18mm conductive disk, which I can drill a hole in.*

Any directions on how I could find those disks at a reasonable price? I am mainly looking for keywords in order to be able to find them, as "disks" or "coins" result in finding mostly unrelated results.

Comment: Can't tell from your question if you are going to rely on the washers to conduct electricity. Steel, including stainless steel, is a terrible electrical conductor. Silicon bronze is much better. Most brasses are probably better than steel also. Also, there are crimps available which can directly crimp nickel strip. Maybe that would be easier if you are so averse to soldering.

Comment: https://electricalline.com/foil-connectors-crimp-wire-foil-and-film

Comment: @mkeith The "solderless" design is chosen in order to make almost every part replaceable, . But yes, I am planning on having it conduct slightly. Also, I quickly looked for the electrical conductivity of stainless steel, and it "only" indicated having a resistance 10 times worse than nickel, however I do not know if in practice this will be significant.

Comment: Well, maybe the best course is to proceed as planned, and then when you first operate it, check to see if the bolt or washer or whatever is getting warm or causing excessive voltage drop. If not you are all set. If there are problems with heat or voltage drop, you can switch to brass or silicon bronze.

Comment: I would crimp a ring lug to the wire, drill a hole in the strip and put the bolt through the lug and strip with a small washer on top of the ring lug.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Oh, thanks for the "ring lug" name, I didn't know the name of those things, thank you! I am already drilling a hole through the strip, the problem however is tightening the strip to the washer so that they contact properly.

Comment: The goal in this type of arrangement is to have the ring lug in direct contact with the nickel strip. You normally do not want to have a washer in between your conductive strip and your ring lug. The washer just acts as a resistor. If there is some reason you can't do that, maybe it is OK to have the washer in between. You will just have to validate it by analysis or test (whichever seems more convenient).

Comment: @mkeith I haven't explained it so well in the post as the guidelines indicated not to rely on pictures, but essentially: I have a 18mm plate that is constantly pressing up. Above that, a small cylindrical plastic bracket makes sure it doesn't move to the sides (and blocks it from moving up as well). I need to place the nickel strip ABOVE the plastic bracket, but it must be firmly held down. To achieve this, I have opted to use a screw, with washers "squeezing" around the plastic bracket and the strip. Anything that makes sure the strip is pressured onto the bracket and the plate works, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. **Mudguard washer**. Image source: [RS](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/c/fasteners-fixings/nuts-washers/mudguard-washers/).*

Alternatives from the comments. Feel free to edit:

- Mudguard washer (east side of Atlantic).
- Fender washer (west side of Atlantic).
- Penny washer.

[image]

*Figure 2. Another possibility - square terminal washers or "amplifier terminal screws" may be adequate to "bite" the edge of the strip you wish to clamp. (Many have the corners turned down as spikes. Image source: Google image search.*

Comment: AKA fender washer

Comment: @Charles: Two countries separated by a common language.

Comment: I can also vouch for the fact that in the US, these are called fender washers. If you went into a hardware store and asked for a mudguard washer I think you would receive a blank stare.

Comment: @Transistor We would buy a fender washer in a hardware store. You?

Comment: Thanks for the name! However, I aaaalmost can't find it small enough. I've found (inner diameter-outer diameter) 4-18mm washers, however I need a 3mm inner diameter and 17mm or more outer diameter (due to M3 screws and the receptacle that blocks the washer from moving).

Comment: @Charles, I've never noticed them called anything special in an Irish hardware store. "Big washer with small hole", if I was to ask.

Comment: Ah, @ZeroZ30o, but all that information was missing from the question.

Comment: @Transistor yes, my bad, I thought the name would've been enough - I'll add those details in. It was very close to being exactly what I needed, though!

Comment: Or "penny washer", available in M3x20 size.

Comment: Or a flange-head screw would allow for a larger hole in the washer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton didn't know about the flange-head screws, though unfortunately the size of the screw head needs to be quite small, for the same reason as why I need to remove the small washer (it contacts with the plate "before" the big washer can). I haven't been able to find the penny washer you mentioned in M3x20 (in aliexpress, ebay), only M3x16 which is again 1mm too short (getting quite unlucky with these sizes, 1mm short again...).

Comment: @ZeroZ30o https://www.rcworld.co.uk/acatalog/M3x20-Penny-Washer-PennyM3x20.html#SID=13 but does it have to be round? Could you get some metal strip of the right width and drill a 3.2 mm hole in it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It does have to be round due to the plastic bracket being cylindrical. I might be able to cut a metal strip into circles (with scissors?), though that seems quite wasteful for the material, but if there is no other option this is what I will go with. Additionally, that M3x20 washer is too big (yes, I know...), but I cannot enter my country in that website either way.

Comment: Accepting answer, since it gives an extremely good overview of all possible options - sadly it's not exactly what I would've wanted, but for someone with a similar problem it should do the trick - thanks everyone! (edit: a friend who is a wizard at searching aliexpress somehow found what I wanted, tho it doesn't have any of the keywords mentioned here, and only 2 sellers provide it)